# I get this Missing or bad plugin while running sonar-runner on a C project

Tags: c, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to analyze a example project which was provided by the sonarQube examples. I have this C/C++ version 2.0 plugin installed on my SonarQube. 
My sonar-project.properties has these contents.

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.projectKey=org.codehaus.sonar:simple-c-project

sonar.projectName=Simple C project analyzed with the SonarQube Runner

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src

sonar.language=c

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

**When i run the sonar-runner command for this project i get an error as given below**

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

Caused by: com.A.A.A.B.A: Missing or bad plugin license. Please check logs.

Am i missing any plugins or is the plugin installed not proper.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C/C++ plugin is a commercial plugin, which requires a purchased licenses. I suspect the problem is that it can't find your licenses.

According to the [official instructions](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/installation-and-usage/), you need to do this:

```
Log in as a System administrator, go to Settings > General Settings > Licenses, paste your license key and Save (was Settings > General Settings > C/C++ (SonarSource) prior to version 1.6).
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use another plugin in sonar called sonar-cxx if you don't want to use the commercial plugin. Its community edition Plugin. You can find it Here- https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Installation

You can download it from here - https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/releases/tag/cxx-0.9.1